ubuntu stuck while rebooting after installation
I tried to reinstall ubuntu 22.04 on my lenovo Thinkpad T480s. I did so successfully until it asked me to restart the laptop. Then it seems to be stuck in a loop while rebooting. I have seen various threads on this topic here and elsewhere but couldn't get any of the solutions get to work for me.
I have played around with the BIOS settings such as boot order, but keep on getting messages like:

error: file /boot/ not found.
system reset
media test failure, check cable

I have repeated the whole installation several times, with various usb sticks and also with ubuntu 24.04 - with the same outcome.
I don't really understand enough about BIOS settings to know what I need to change. Would really appreciate some (beginner-friendly) guidance!

You don't provide clear details as to what Ubuntu product you're trying to (re-)install, as Ubuntu Server & Ubuntu Desktop use different installers; you only mention release(s). Next you've not said what type of install; is this is a clean install (ie. overwrite what you had previously; more likely to succeed*), or an unclean install (ie. non-destructive & trying to keep what you had previously etc), ie. some details of what type of install you're attempting & options selected.  Did you write ISO to media correctly (boot can fail to write if not correctly written and you do mention boot)

Hi guiverc, thanks for asking  for clarifications.
I'm trying to install ubuntu Desktop.
yes, I did a clean install (overwrite everything)
writing ISO to media: I think that was successful. I used 'startup disk creator' to make a bootable usb stick and since the installation itself worked, I assumed it's not a problem with the usb stick.
The rebooting issue arises after it asks me to 'remove the external drive and press ENTER'.

If your boot loader has a problem, repairing it using a live USB Ubuntu maybe could solve it, here is what you should do :
First create a live bootable Ubuntu and run it in live test mode.
Then open terminal and run sudo apt update
Then run :
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair

Repairing boot might solve it but if it did not maybe these steps in bios worked :
Test both UEFI and Legacy boot mode
Turn off secure boot mode
If none of these worked reinstall Ubuntu and if needed configure boot partition manually.
EDIT :
Based on your comment, it looks like your device is trying to boot from a network device and failing, here is step by step guide :
First Enter your bios
Then Check and Set Boot Order:
Look for the Boot or Startup tab.
Ensure your hard drive (or SSD) is set as the first boot device. Move it to the top of the boot order list.
Disable any options related to network boot (PXE boot).
Under the same Boot or Startup tab, look for options related to Network Boot or PXE Boot, turn all of them off.
Press F10 save and exit.
If issue persists please tell me in the comments

Thanks for the susggestions, but unfortunately boot-repair didn't work, nor the bios settings you suggested.
I reinstalled with overwriting disk, got the message that installation is completed. I reboot with secure boot mode off, both UEFI/Legacy boot  enabled with UEFI firs,t but again after rebooting it seems stuck in this loop:

initializing and establishing link
PXE-E61:media test failure, check cable
PXE-M0F : exiting intel boot agent
reset system
How do I configure the boot partition manually?

You're welcome, Do you still get error: file /boot/ not found?

no, now I just get 'media test failure, check cable' message...

So it looks like your device is trying to boot from a network device and failing, please check my answer again, I have provided step by step guide for you

I still get the same 'media test failure' message if I use Legacy only. I don't get that message when I use both, UEFI and LEGACY or UEFI only. But either way it still doesn't boot properly. It says 'reset system' and repeats.

So you turned off network boot and set your Ubuntu drive and boot loader as default?

Yes. my boot priority order now is 1. NVMe0 WDC PC SN720 SDAQNTW-512G-1001 2. ATA HDDO, 3. USB HDD, 4. Other HDD, 5. Other CD, 6. USB FDD, 7. USB CD. Excluded from boot priority order: PCI LAN. ... Under the same 'startup' Network boot I can only select options, not disable, and selected NVMe0. ...UEFI/Legacy Boot now both are enabled with UEFI first and CMS Support Yes.

Okay I don't know what was wrong but here's what I did in my last try:
reset all BIOS settings to default. turn on secure boot. make sure harddrive is first boot priority. And then it worked. I don't understand what was off, but thank you so much for your help anyways.
